# Python matplotlib Volumecandle chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

My question is about matplotlib. Is there any tool to plot Volumecandle charts or ist it possible to change the width value within a for loop? I tried it by myself and failed alot.

```
candlestick_ohlc(ax1, df_ohlc.values, width=5, colorup='g')
```

The chart I want to produce is calles Volumecandle chart. It's a chart where the volume is added into the different candles. Shown [here](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:chart_analysis:candlevolume):

[image]

However, the command from above fails to generate the individuel thickness of each candlestick. I dont know exactly how to do it. I know you could do it with a for loop within a pandas dataframe but the module `candlestick_ohlc` does not (as far as I can tell) support an itereation within width. Width should be change for every candlestick.

OK thx guys i think i have it

```
df = web.DataReader('AMD','yahoo','2012-01-01','2013-03-30')

# get new column
df['VC'] =0# set all to 0
x=0
for i in df['VC']:
    df.ix[x,'VC']=df.ix[x,'Volume']*0.00000004 #to expand the size of each   
    x+=1

#plot from tutorial
df_ohlc = df['Adj Close'].resample('10D').ohlc()
df_volume = df['VC'].resample('10D').sum()

df_ohlc.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_ohlc['Date'] = df_ohlc['Date'].map(mdates.date2num)

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=5, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
ax1.xaxis_date()
```

## solution to plot volumecharts

```
x=0
for i in df_volume:

    candlestick_ohlc(ax1, df_ohlc.values[x:x+1], width=i,    colorup='g',colordown='r')
    x += 1                               
ax2.fill_between(df_volume.index.map(mdates.date2num), df_volume.values, 0)
plt.show()
```

[Volumechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaHWF.png)

Comment: here the link to the tutorial im using.https://pythonprogramming.net/more-stock-data-manipulation-python-programming-for-finance/

Comment: What is a "Volumecandle" chart exactly? Is it the "candlestick" chart shown in the tutorial? Next, what exactly did fail? In how far did it fail? See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: HI, no the chart is not shown in the tutorial. Its a chart where teh volume is added into the different candles. Shown here http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:chart_analysis:candlevolume    It fail to generate the individuel thickness of each candlestick. I dont know exactly how to do it. I know you could do it with a for loop within a panda dataframe but the module candlestick_ohlc doesnt support (i think) a itereation within width.  width should be change for every candlestick

Comment: Ok, would you please [edit] your question, such that is becomes clear what you are looking for and also what problem you have achieving this?!

Comment: In principle you can easily edit the candlestick function to allow for a list of widths instead of only a single number. But the problem is that the required Chart scales its axes non-linearly with time, i.e. dates with high volume take more space on the axes than days with low volume. This would make it necessary to introduce a complete new axis scaling mechanism to the plot, which would make all of this quite complicated. So yes it's possible, but it's a little bit of work to get there.

Comment: [link]In principle you can easily edit the candlestick function to allow for a list of widths instead of only a single number.[link] Can you show me some example? Im not sure if i was on the right way. I need it to check my solution. Im quite new to python. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you have a problem with implementation, you can edit your question to show what you have tried and at what point it fails.